# Binary operator expected, but there is a binary operator as in the division symbol

Tags: ada

Hello I get `binary operator expected` in the begin section of the function. How do I fix this?

```
procedure  float_test is
    A : Integer := 3;
    B : Integer := 2;
    F : Float;
begin
    F := (Float) A / (Float) B;
end float_test;
```

I got the code from [here: adacore.com](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/strongly_typed_language.html#strong-typing)

```
procedure  float_test is
    A : Integer := 3;
    B : Integer := 2;
    F : Float;
begin
    F := A / B;
end float_test;
```

The description says: `The offending line must be changed to F := Float (A) / Float (B); in order to be accepted by the compiler.`

Comment: I don't see the above code anywhere on the page you linked. it doesn't appear to be legal Ada. It does say "The offending line must be changed to F := Float (A) / Float (B); in order to be accepted by the compiler." But that's not what you wrote.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I see my error now... For reference when simple mistakes happen is it best to just delete the question? Never mind, there is a posted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ada, you do casts using a slightly different syntax (looks like you are using the syntax that C expects instead)

Instead do:

```
F := Float(A) / Float(B);
```